# Fluid width block element links in fixed position footer

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer, fluid-layout

I am trying to create a bottom aligned, fluid width sticky footer that contains three links that are the same height as the container, which also have fluid widths.

I have created a top aligned version of this footer, where the links are not the full height of their container. It breaks if I set the bottom of the container to zero. I have put the code for this here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bHJR3/1/

How can I modify what I have so the bottom edge of the container is flush with the bottom of the window, and the links are the same height as the container?

I know how to do this through jquery but I am trying to avoid js if at all possible.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
Here's a jquery solution I came up with in case of no answers if anybody wants to see it. http://jsfiddle.net/bHJR3/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it broke when you set `bottom: 0` on `#footer` is because everything inside `#footer` had `position: absolute`. Absolutely positioned elements do not take up any space in the document flow and will not cause their parent elements to expand to contain them. Setting a height on `#footer` solves this. Setting `height: 100%` on the `a` tags will cause them to size relative to their parent element. You can keep `div.content`, but you would also have to set `height: 100%` on it.

Add the following CSS to `#footer`:

```
bottom: 0;
height: 90px;
```

Add the following CSS to `A`:

```
height: 100%;
line-height: 90px; /* matches the height from #footer to vertically center the link text */
```

Remove `div.content`. It doesn't seem necessary here.

**Edit**

You can center the footer by adding/changing the following CSS on `#footer`:

```
width: 640px;
left: 50%; /* positions left edge of #footer to center of page */
margin-left: -320px; /* pulls footer to the left (width / 2) * -1 */
```

**Edit**

You can use max-width and a media query to alter the styling of the footer if the window width is < 640px:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    height: 114px;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -320px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #footer {
        margin-left: auto;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ryan Thanks, but `margin-top: 81%` with a pixel based height? Not quite right.

Comment: updated it, thought I had done that already its using bottom now. Doh!

Comment: Much better! A nitpicking side note: bad idea to set `height: 114px` on multiple elements - it's better to use `height: 100%` on the children so you only have to worry about changing the height on the top level parent. However, in this case `div.content` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I have trouble keeping the footer centered without the content div, maybe I'm noobing something up though. The only issue I see with this solution is that I'm trying to keep the height/width ratio the same regardless of window size. I apologize for not stating this in my question, this is the answer to the question I posted.

Comment: @tuck What is the width of the footer supposed to be?

Comment: The width is supposed at most be 640px but never be wider than the window. The behavior I get out of the js solution I posted is exactly what I'm looking for, just without the js :)